# JS: Iterate through a list using a timeout without async/await

Tags: javascript

I have a list of divs I am iterating through.  I think I figured it out using async/await:

```
let list = document.querySelectorAll('div')

async function goThrough() {
   for (let x = 0; x < list.length; x++) {
     let foo= await new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(x)
          resolve();
        }, 5000)
     });
   }
}

goThrough();
```

This seems to be logging each div node in the list with 5 seconds between them.  I can't figure out how to do this using straight Promises though, without the luxury of async/await.  I'm fine using async/await but curiosity has gotten the better of me and just trying to break it down to see if I can do it without it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use recursion and call each promise only after the previous one was completed.

```
function goThrough(index, total) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(index), 1000);
  }).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    if (index + 1 < total) {
      goThrough(index + 1, total);
    }
  });
}

const list = document.querySelectorAll("div");
goThrough(0, list.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go through the list recursively, no need to use Promises:

```js
const list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

function goThrough(list, iList = 0) {
  if (iList >= list.length) {
    return;
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`list[${iList}] = ${list[iList]}`);
    goThrough(list, iList + 1);
  }, 5000);
}

goThrough(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to use `list` for what it already is - an iterable. The example below uses [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) library:

```
import {pipeAsync, delay} from 'iter-ops';

const i = pipeAsync(list, delay(1000)); //=> AsyncIterable

// testing:
(async function() {
    for await(const a of i) {
        console.log(a); // each value delayed by 1s
    }
})();
```

And you can iterate through the async result without `asyc/await`, if that's what you really want, though it's just needlessly awkward.